# NOT IN query with Doctrine QueryBuilder in a Many to Many relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many, query-builder

In my Symfony2 project, I have two entities "contact" and "settings", with a many to many relationship :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Settings", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $settings;
```

Entity settings have a property "parametre", which is a simple string.

Now I want to get all the contacts that DON'T have any settings which "parametre" is "THEMES".

I can do that in SQL with a query like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.id) FROM contact c WHERE c.id
NOT IN (SELECT cs.contact_id FROM contact_settings cs
INNER JOIN Settings s ON s.id = cs.settings_id
WHERE s.parametre = "THEMES")
```

But I can't figure out how to do it with Doctrine's query builder.
Here's what I've tried so far :

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
    ->join('c.settings', 's');

$qb2 = $qb;

$qb2->select('s2')
    ->from('AppBundle\Entity\Settings', 's')
    ->where('s2.parametre = :parametre');

$query->where(($qb->expr()->notIn('s', $qb2->getDQL())));
$query->setParameter('parametre', 'THEMES');
$result = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

That doesn't return any result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$subQueryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$subQuery = $subQueryBuilder
    ->select(['cs.id'])
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Contact', 'cs')
    ->innerJoin('cs.settings', 's')
    ->where('s.parameter = :parameter')
    ->setParameter('parameter', 'THEMES')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult()
;

$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select(['c'])
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Contact', 'c')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('c.id', ':subQuery'))
    ->setParameter('subQuery', $subQuery)
    ->getQuery()
;

$result = $query->getResult();
```

This is just an example to your question. I can't provide complete example as I don't know the structure of your entities...

Comment: I can't do ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:ContactSettings', 'cs') since I don't have a ContactSettings entity. Should I have one?

Comment: I must admit that I don't really get it. Why should I have an entity that wouldn't have any fields (except for the two referenced entities)? I always thought if you needed a many to many relationship without any extra field, you didn't have to create the entity and only needed the @ORM\ManyToMany annotation.

Comment: @Lo' I edited my answer.. What I showed you is not a real solution to your question, it is just an example..

Comment: This fires two queries, what is not the best solution at all.

Comment: @ThomasKekeisen Yes, I know. But this is how subqueries work.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer from xurshid29 will use 2 queries. But by using the getDQL() inside the "->notIn()" function you can do it in 1 query:

```
$subQueryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$subQuery = $subQueryBuilder
    ->select('cs.id')
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Contact', 'cs')
    ->innerJoin('cs.settings', 's')
    ->where('s.parameter = :parameter') // move setParameter() to main queryBuilder!
;

$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query = $queryBuilder
    ->select('c')
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Contact', 'c')
    ->where($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('c.id', $subQuery->getDQL()))
    ->setParameter('parameter', 'THEMES') // setParameter() from the subQuery must go here
    ->getQuery()
;

$result = $query->getResult();
```

Warning! Do not try to set the DQL as a parameter, it will result in a string instead of real SQL syntax.
**So this is wrong and will not work**:

```
// THIS IS WRONG
->where($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('c.id', ':subQuery'))
->setParameter('subQuery', $subQuery->getDQL())
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!

Note: Got `Too few parameters: the query defines 1 parameters but you only bound 0` exception until I moved `->setParameter('parameter', 'THEMES')` below `->where($queryBuilder->expr()->notIn('c.id', $subQuery->getDQL()))`