# Must be a CollectionValuedAssociationField trying to find not in Many To Many

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

With entities of Artist and Show in a ManyToMany relationship, trying to build a form that lists existing artists not yet in a given show results in the error

> Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a
> CollectionValuedAssociationField

#### Edit:

There is the expression `notIn($x, $y)` at [Doctrine's documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) but it is not at all clear (i.e., attempts have failed) how that can be used in a form class.

#### Edit 2:

The expected results can be obtained in an Artist Repository with the function appearing below.  It is not usable in the form class, though, because its result is not an instance of QueryBuilder! [With thanks to xurshid29's [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008726/not-in-query-with-doctrine-querybuilder-in-a-many-to-many-relation) here.]

```
public function notInShow($show)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $ids = $qb
        ->select('a.id')
        ->from('AppBundle:Artist', 'a', 'a.id')
        ->leftJoin('a.shows', 's')
        ->where('s.show = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $show->getShow())
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

    $ids = array_keys($ids);

    $qbA = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Artist a '
        . 'WHERE a.id NOT IN (:ids)')
        ->setParameter(':ids', $ids)
        ->getResult();

    return $qbA;
}
```

The latest attempt (of many) to build a field looks like this:

Form class (snippet):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $show = $options['show'];
    $builder->add('artists', EntityType::class,
        [
            'class' => Artist::class,
            'choice_label' => function($artist, $key, $index) {
                return $artist->getLastName() . ', ' . $artist->getFirstName();
            },
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($show) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->join('a.shows', 's')
                        ->where('a NOT MEMBER of s')
                        ->andWhere('IDENTITY(s) = :show')
                        ->setParameter(':show', $show->getId())
                        ->orderBy('a.firstName', 'ASC')
                        ->orderBy('a.lastName', 'ASC')
                ;
            },
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
    ]);
}
```

Entity snippets:

Artist:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Show", mappedBy="artists")
 */
protected $shows;
```

Show:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="shows", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="participation",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="show_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      ))
 */
protected $artists;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last! A few final tweaks and this works:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $show = $options['show'];
    $builder->add('artists', EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => Artist::class,
                'choice_label' => function($artist, $key, $index) {
                    return $artist->getLastName() . ', ' . $artist->getFirstName();
                },
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use($show) {
                    $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('a');
                    $ids = $qb
                        ->select('a.id')
                        ->leftJoin('a.shows', 's')
                        ->where('s.show = ?1')
                        ->setParameter(1, $show->getShow())
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getResult();
                    if (empty($ids)) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a');
                    } else {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                            ->where($er->createQueryBuilder('a')->expr()->notIn('a.id', ':ids'))
                            ->setParameter(':ids', $ids);
                    }
                },
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
        ])
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'Add artist(s)',
                'label_format' => ['class' => 'text-bold']
    ));
}
```